# 3 Questions on hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

could some help me answer any one these questions? The answers are given I just don't know how to solve them. Any help would be great!

1. Could two 3-dimensional "hyperplanes" in R^6 have a single point of intersection? (Yes)
2. Could two 4-dimensional "hyperplanes" in R^6 have a single point of intersection? (No)
3. What are possible dimensions of intersection of a 7-dimensional and an 8-dimensional "hyperplanes" in R^10? (dimensions 5,6,7, or empty intersection) 
   Note: empty intersection is possible only if we allow "hyperplanes" defined by non-homogeneous equations. In case of subspaces (given by homogeneous equations) zero vector always belongs to the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give the first one a try.

If we are in $\mathbb R^n$, then an $(n-1)$-dimension hyperplane is given by one equation. An $(n-k)$-dimensional hyperplane is given by $k$ equations. (To convince your self of this fact, try $n=1,2,3$, and various $k$ values.)

Thus, each 3-dimensional hyperplane in $\mathbb R^6$ is given by three equations, so seeking their intersection is given by the equation $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a  $6\times6$-matrix. If we imagine it in the row reduced echelon form, then if all the columns of $A$ are pivot columns, then there is exactly one solution.

See if you can try and extend this type of reasoning to the second problem.